# Using Fold to calculate the result of linear recurrence relying on multiple previous values

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have a linear recurrence problem where the next element relies on more than just the prior value, e.g. the Fibonacci sequence.  One method calculating the n<sup>th</sup> element is to define it via a function call, e.g.

```
Fibonacci[0] = 0; Fibonacci[1] = 1;
Fibonacci[n_Integer?Positive] := Fibonacci[n] + Fibonacci[n - 1]
```

and for the sequence I'm working with, that is exactly what I do.  (The definition is inside of a `Module` so I don't pollute `` Global` ``.)  However, I am going to be using this with 2<sup>10</sup> - 2<sup>13</sup> points, so I'm concerned about the extra overhead when I just need the last term and none of the prior elements.  I'd like to use `Fold` to do this, but `Fold` only passes the immediately prior result which means it is not directly useful for a general linear recurrence problem.

I'd like a pair of functions to replace `Fold` and `FoldList` that pass a specified number of prior sequence elements to the function, i.e.

```
In[1] := MultiFoldList[f, {1,2}, {3,4,5}] (* for lack of a better name *)
Out[1]:= {1, 2, f[3,2,1], f[4,f[3,2,1],2], f[5,f[4,f[3,2,1],2],f[3,2,1]]}
```

I had something that did this, but I closed the notebook prior to saving it.  So, if I rewrite it on my own, I'll post it.

**Edit**: as to why I am not using `RSolve` or `MatrixPower` to solve this.  My specific problem is I'm performing an [n-point Pade approximant](http://books.google.com/books?id=kfNQAAAAMAAJ&q=inauthor%3a%22George+Allen+Baker%22&dq=inauthor%3a%22George+Allen+Baker%22&hl=en&ei=lJl9TezGMYO0lQeFifHVBQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=2&ved=0CC8Q6AEwAQ) to analytically continue a function I only know at a set number of points on the imaginary axis, {z<sub>i</sub>}.  Part of creating the approximant is to generate a set of coefficients, a<sub>i</sub>, which is another recurrence relation, that are then fed into the final relationship

```
A[n+1]== A[n] + (z - z[[n]]) a[[n+1]] A[n-1]
```

which is not amenable to either `RSolve` nor `MatrixPower`, at least that I can see.

Comment: Is the built in [Pade approximant](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/PadeApproximation.html) no good in the case that you want?

Comment: The problem is my function is numerical, i.e. I only know it at certain points, and the built-in function approximates known functions. So, I can't give it a list and have it give me a function back. Nor, do the other built-in interpolating functions work as they don't do rational interpolation, and my function will most likely have poles. So, rational interpolation is necessary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can [RecurrenceTable](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/RecurrenceTable.html) perform this task for you?

Find the 1000th term in a recurrence depending on two previous values:

```
In[1]:= RecurrenceTable[{a[n] == a[n - 1] + a[n - 2], 
  a[1] == a[2] == 1}, a, 
   {n, {1000}}]

Out[1]= {4346655768693745643568852767504062580256466051737178040248172\
9089536555417949051890403879840079255169295922593080322634775209689623\
2398733224711616429964409065331879382989696499285160037044761377951668\
49228875}
```

**Edit:** If your recurrence is defined by a function `f[m, n]` that doesn't like to get evaluated for non-numeric m and n, then you could use [Condition](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Condition.html):

```
In[2]:= f[m_, n_] /; IntegerQ[m] && IntegerQ[n] := m + n
```

The recurrence table in terms of `f`:

```
In[3]:= RecurrenceTable[{a[n] == f[a[n - 1], a[n - 2]], 
  a[1] == a[2] == 1}, a, {n, {1000}}]

Out[3]= {4346655768693745643568852767504062580256466051737178040248172\
9089536555417949051890403879840079255169295922593080322634775209689623\
2398733224711616429964409065331879382989696499285160037044761377951668\
49228875}
```

Comment: +1, I need to become more familiar with the "recent" additions to the standard functions. It does exactly what I need it to. I had to wrap it in `Quiet` as the recurrence references external lists and `Part` just does not like having an undefined variable passed to it ...

Comment: Interesting use of condition. I never think to use it quite like that. For the edit alone, I wish I could add another +1.

Comment: (+1) Just a small comment that checking `Head`s is faster than pattern matching, so `f[m_Integer,n_Integer]` would be faster than `f[m_, n_] /; IntegerQ[m] && IntegerQ[n]`.

Answer (score 4):

A multiple foldlist can be useful but it would not be an efficient way to get linear recurrences evaluated for large inputs. A couple of alternatives are to use RSolve or matrix powers times a vector of initial values.

Here are these methods applied to example if nth term equal to n-1 term plus two times n-2 term.

```
f[n_] =  f[n] /. RSolve[{f[n] == f[n - 1] + 2*f[n - 2], f[1] == 1, f[2] == 1},
  f[n], n][[1]]
```

Out[67]= 1/3 (-(-1)^n + 2^n)

```
f2[n_Integer] := Last[MatrixPower[{{0, 1}, {2, 1}}, n - 2].{1, 1}]

{f[11], f2[11]}
```

Out[79]= {683, 683}

Daniel Lichtblau
Wolfram Research

Comment: +1, for suggesting two reasonable approaches that I'd use if my specific case allowed it. Trust me, I really wanted to!

Answer (score 3):

Almost a convoluted joke, but you could use a side-effect of `NestWhileList`

```
fibo[n_] := 
  Module[{i = 1, s = 1}, 
   NestWhileList[ s &, 1, (s = Total[{##}]; ++i < n) &, 2]];
```

Not too bad performance:

```
In[153]:= First@Timing@fibo[10000]
Out[153]= 0.235
```

By changing the last `2` by any integer you may pass the last k results to your function (in this case Total[]).

Answer (score 2):

`LinearRecurrence` and `RecurrenceTable` are very useful.

For small kernels, the `MatrixPower` method that Daniel gave is the fastest.

For some problems these may not be applicable, and you may need to roll your own.

I will be using Nest because I believe that is appropriate for this problem, but a similar construct can be used with Fold.

A specific example, the Fibonacci sequence.  This may not be the cleanest possible for that, but I believe you will see the utility as I continue.

```
fib[n_] :=
  First@Nest[{##2, # + #2} & @@ # &, {1, 1}, n - 1]

fib[15]

Fibonacci[15]
```

Here I use `Apply` (`@@`) so that I can address elements with `#`, `#2`, etc., rathern than `#[[1]]` etc.  I use `SlotSequence` to drop the first element from the old list, and `Sequence` it into the new list at the same time.

If you are going to operate on the entire list at once, then a simple `Append[Rest@#, ...` may be better.  Either method can be easily generalized.  For example, a simple linear recurrence implementation is

```
 lr[a_, b_, n_Integer] := First@Nest[Append[Rest@#, a.#] &, b, n - 1]

 lr[{1,1}, {1,1}, 15]
```

(the kernel is in reverse order from the built in `LinearRecurrence`)

Comment: +1, this looks a lot like the method I came up with for `Fold` directly. And the `Append[Rest@#]` method is really nice.