# Error in RecurrenceTable with symbolic input

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I am finally working on my [n-point Pade code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5294376/using-fold-to-calculate-the-result-of-linear-recurrence-relying-on-multiple-previ), again, and I am running across an error that was not occurring previously. The heart of the matter revolves around this code:

```
zi = {0.1, 0.2, 0.3}
ai = {0.904837, 1.05171, -0.499584}

Quiet[ RecurrenceTable[ {A[0] == 0, A[1] == ai[[1]],
          A[n+1]==A[n] + (z - zi[[n]]) ai[[n+1]] A[n-1]},
          A, {n, Length@ai -1 } ],
   {Part::pspec}]
```

(The use of `Quiet` is necessary as `Part` complains about `zi[[n]]` and `ai[[n+1]]` when `n` is purely symbolic.)  The code itself is part of a function that I want a symbolic result from, hence `z` is a `Symbol`. But, when I run the above code I get the error:

```
RecurrenceTable::nlnum1: 
  The function value {0.904837,0.904837+0. z} is not a list of numbers with 
  dimensions {2} when the arguments are {0,0.,0.904837}.
```

Note the term `{0.904837,0.904837+0. z}` where `0. z` is not reduced to zero.  What do I need to do to force it to evaluate to zero, as it seems to be the source of the problem? Are there alternatives?

Additionally, as a general complaint about the help system for the Wolfram Research personnel who haunt stackoverflow: in v.7 `RecurrenceTable::nlnum1` is not searchable! Nor, does the `>>` link at the end of the error take you to the error definition, but takes you to the definition of `RecurrenceTable`, instead, where the common errors are not cross-referenced.

**Edit**: After reviewing my code, the solution I came up with was to evaluate the `RecurrenceTable` completely symbolically, including the initial conditions.  The working code is as follows:

```
Clear[NPointPade, NPointPadeFcn]
NPointPade[pts : {{_, _} ..}] := NPointPade @@ Transpose[pts]

NPointPade[zi_List, fi_List] /; Length[zi] == Length[fi] :=
 Module[{ap, fcn, rec},
  ap = {fi[[1]]};
  fcn = Module[{gp = #, zp, res},
     zp =  zi[[-Length@gp ;;]];
     res = (gp[[1]] - #)/((#2 - zp[[1]]) #) &[Rest@gp, Rest@zp];
     AppendTo[ap, res[[1]]];
     res
  ] &;

  NestWhile[fcn, fi, (Length[#] > 1 &)];

 (*
  The recurrence relation is used twice, with different initial conditions, so
  pre-evaluate it to pass along to NPointPadeFcn
 *)
 rec[aif_, zif_, a_, b_][z_] := 
  Evaluate[RecurrenceTable[
     {A[n + 1] == A[n] + (z - zif[n])*aif[n + 1]*A[n - 1], 
      A[0] == a, A[1] == b}, 
     A, {n, {Length@ap - 1}}][[1]]];

  NPointPadeFcn[{zi, ap, rec }]
 ]

NPointPadeFcn[{zi_List, ai_List, rec_}][z_] /; Length[zi] == Length[ai] :=
 Module[{aif, zif},
  zif[n_Integer] /; 1 <= n <= Length[zi] := zi[[n]];
  aif[n_Integer] /; 1 <= n <= Length[zi] := ai[[n]];
  rec[aif, zif, 0, ai[[1]]][z]/rec[aif, zif, 1, 1][z]
 ]

Format[NPointPadeFcn[x_List]] := NPointPadeFcn[Shallow[x, 1]];
```

Like the built-in interpolation functions, `NPointPade` does some pre-processing, and returns a function that can be evaluated, `NPointPadeFcn`.  The pre-processing done by `NPointPade` generates the list of `ai`s from the `zi`s and the function values at those points, in addition to pre-evaluating the recurrence relations. When `NPointPadeFcn` is supplied with a `z` value, it evaluates two linear recurrence relations by supplying it with the appropriate values.

**Edit**: for the curious, here's `NPointPade` in operation

[image: NPointPade in action]

In the first plot, it is difficult to tell the difference between the two functions, but the second plot shows the absolute (blue) and relative (red) errors. As written, it takes a very long time to create a Pade for 20 points, so I need to work on speeding it up. But, for now, it works.

Comment: @rcollyer Using `WorkingPrecision->Infinity` in both calls to `RecurrenceTable` fixes the problem. The issue was that `tmp` contained `aif[1.]` and the likes, which did not match against your patterns following `RecurrenceTable` calls.

Comment: @Sasha, I fixed it another way entirely, see above. I'm still giving you credit, as your idea of delaying the evaluation of the `ai`s was the correct one. As a side not, changing the `WorkingPrecision` doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: For my curiosity, would you give an example using your updated function?

Comment: Thanks.  Why does your syntax highlighting show pink/magenta `#` slot symbols?

Comment: @Mr. Wizard: probably because he changed them? You can change colors in preferences. No need to edit internal noteboos.

Comment: @d'o-o'b I suppose that could be, but by default a similar color is used to indicate a Slot without a matching Function.

Comment: @Mr. Wizard: Isn't it red in that case and not pink/magenta?

Comment: @d'o-o'b not on my system; maybe I am the one using strange syntax highlighting, or maybe it varies from platform to platform?  If you type `# + #2` on a new line without anything else, what color are `#` and `#2`?

Comment: I think I have a couple of improvements to your `NPointPade` function:


`NPointPade[pts : {{_, _} ..}] := NPointPade @@ (pts\[Transpose])`

And an inner function:

`res = (gp[[1]] - #)/((#2 - zp[[1]]) #) &[Rest@gp, Rest@zp];`

These test faster for me.


Also, you seem to have a couple of orphan symbols in the `Module` in `NPointPadeFcn`: `A` and `B`

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, as to the colors: the color I use for a non-matching `Slot` is very red, as the default matching and non-matching colors were very difficult to readily differentiate on my screen. Orphan symbols, argh! I will fix those, and apply your fixes.

Comment: @rcollyer Could you give me a reference to the logic of this code, i.e. the method used to constuct n-Pade approximation ? Why do you call it Pade ?

Comment: @Sasha, the standard is [Essentials of Pade Approximants](http://www.amazon.com/gp/search?index=books&linkCode=qs&keywords=012074855X) by Baker, and the method is called n-point Pade approximation. This is more correctly referred to as *rational interpolation*, but since it uses the ideas in forming Pade approximants, either is correct. Through your linke-in profile, I have access to your email, and I can send you a summary of the method tomorrow, if you'd like. The comment field is not the best place for this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can hide part extraction behind a function:

```
In[122]:= zi = {0.1, 0.2, 0.3};
ai = {0.904837, 1.05171, -0.499584};

In[124]:= zif[n_Integer] /; 1 <= n <= Length[zi] := zi[[n]]
aif[n_Integer] /; 1 <= n <= Length[ai] := ai[[n]]

In[127]:= RecurrenceTable[{A[0] == 0, A[1] == aif[1], 
  A[n + 1] == 
   A[n] + (z - zif[n]) aif[n + 1] A[n - 1]}, A, {n, (Length@ai) - 1}]

Out[127]= {0.904837, 0.904837, 
 0.904837 - 0.271451 aif[4] + 0.904837 z aif[4]}
```

---

**EDIT**

Here is the work-around for the problem:

```
In[4]:= zi = {0.1, 0.2, 0.3};
ai = {0.904837, 1.05171, -0.499584};

In[6]:= zif[n_Integer] /; 1 <= n <= Length[zi] := zi[[n]]
aif[n_Integer] /; 1 <= n <= Length[ai] := ai[[n]]

In[8]:= Block[{aif, zif}, 
 RecurrenceTable[{A[0] == 0, A[1] == aif[1], 
   A[n + 1] == A[n] + (z - zif[n]) aif[n + 1] A[n - 1]}, 
  A, {n, 0, (Length@ai) - 1}]]

Out[8]= {0, 0.904837, 0.904837}
```

`Block` serves to temporarily remove definitions of `aif` and `zif` while `RecurrenceTable` is executed. Then, when `Block` exits, the values are restored, and the output of `RecurrenceTable` evaluates.

Comment: @Sasha: this is probably stupid, but shouldn't it be aif[3] rather than aif[4] above? and where is A[0]?

Comment: @Phi, you are right. Clear definitions of `zif` and `aif` and rerun `RecurrenceTable`. This is the output I would expect. But if we redefine `aif` and `zif`, and rerun the `RecurrenceTable` the same odd output is obtains. Looks like a bug. Good catch!

Comment: @Sasha, I'm still getting the error. Nice attempt, but it doesn't seem to like me.

Comment: @rcollyer, I am getting the same result as @Sasha with no error message on Mathematica v.8 but it's only that the result is odd as noted above. @sasha clearing definitions does not change the output for me

Comment: @Phi You also need to replace `A[1]==ai[[1]]` with `A[1]==aif[1]`, clear definitions and then rerun `RecurrenceTable`

Comment: Correction, if you change the order of evaluation where the `tmp = RecurrenceTable[...]` is evaluated before `aif` and `zif` are defined, you get something. But, the error pops back up when I use it in `Plot`, i.e. it is only masked

Comment: @sasha: cleared everything, no change. It seems to me RecurrenceTable has to be further debugged on the mathematica development side

Comment: @Phil, at one point, this worked for me. But, then I changed the code to allow for another scenario - which never worked, anyway. However, when I attempted to return the code to the working form, it no longer worked. I don't know what I changed.  I'll post the full code above and see if more eyes can tell me what went wrong.

Answer (score 3):

It seems to me that Sasha's approach can be mimicked by just `Block`ing `Part`.

```
zi = {0.1, 0.2, 0.3};
ai = {0.904837, 1.05171, -0.499584};

Block[{Part},
 RecurrenceTable[{A[0] == 0, A[1] == ai[[1]], 
   A[n + 1] == A[n] + (z - zi[[n]]) ai[[n + 1]] A[n - 1]}, 
  A, {n, Length@ai - 1}]
]
```

```
   {0, 0.904837, 0.904837}
```

---

Addressing Sasha's criticism, here are two other ways one might approach this:

```
With[{Part = $z}, 
  RecurrenceTable[{A[0] == 0, A[1] == ai[[1]], 
    A[n + 1] == A[n] + (z - zi[[n]]) ai[[n + 1]] A[n - 1]}, 
   A, {n, Length@ai - 1}]
] /. $z -> Part
```

-

```
With[{Part = Hold[Part]}, 
  RecurrenceTable[{A[0] == 0, A[1] == ai[[1]], 
    A[n + 1] == A[n] + (z - zi[[n]]) ai[[n + 1]] A[n - 1]}, 
   A, {n, Length@ai - 1}]
] // ReleaseHold
```

Comment: +1, it does, and it's simpler. I'll consider changing the accepted answer.

Comment: I would be cautious here. You do not know whether `Part` is ever used inside `RecurrenceTable` code. Doing what you suggest might work here, but is a good generic method to invite troubles. I do not mind rcollyer to revert the accept answer, just warning of possible dire consequences of disabling `Part` while executing system commands.

Comment: @Sasha, good point.  If RecurrenceTable were a kernel function, could this be presumed safe?

Comment: I would say no, but I do not know for sure.